# Solved - Java ShakeDetector triggers multiple times - How to get last output?

Tags: java, android, dice, shake, sensors

So I wrote an android app for dice rolling, with adjustable dice (D4-100), amounts and bonuses.
It works all fine when I press the roll button, but I also wanted it to react to shaking my phone.
The problem is, when i shake it once, it displays the result, but if i shake for too long, the shown results get visibly overwritten - I don't want the user to just keep on shaking until the result is accepted!. 
Is there some way to gather all ShakeEvents and only trigger the last one that occured?
Here's what's inside onCreate related to those ShakeEvents:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
ShakeDetector shakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(this);
shakeDetector.start(sensorManager);
```

and here's the "hearShake()" method (from Square, Inc.'s seismic):

```
@Override
public void hearShake() {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Rolling...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(250,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
  } else {
   v.vibrate(250);
  }
  rollButton.performClick();
}
```

**Solution**: 
in `rollButton.performClick();`  I added `long lastShake = System.currentTimeMillis();` 
 
The content of `hearShake()` is wrapped inside `if (separateShake())`:

```
public boolean separateShake(){
        return ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastShake) > 3000) ? true : false;
    }
```

Now `rollButton.performClick()` only gets triggered if there's at least a 3 second delay between the shakes, which is fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to record the time at which the shake is recorded and ignore any additional shakes that occur within, say, the next 3 seconds.  That way they'd have to do quite a long shake for it to count as multiple.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Added the code to my question.